# Video player on Ionic with VueJs

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, ionic-framework, video

What is the best available way to play videos on ionic apps combined with VueJs, supported by both Android and IOS ?

html5 video does not seem to offer enough flexibility (fullscreen ...), and Ionic native video is only supported by Android and can be used only with Angular and not VueJs.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib is it compatible with VueJs or just Reat and Angular ?

Comment: i haven't tried it with VUE.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib It does not work with VueJs

Comment: did it solve your Issue?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib No it did not, but thanks anyway